# Acer Aspire 772 + Ubuntu 23.04: Keyboard / Touchpad not working after suspend

Tags: keyboard, suspend, touchpad

On my Acer Aspire V3-772G Ubuntu 23.04 is installed. When the laptop enters suspend mode (by closing the lid for example) touchpad and keyboard stop working after the laptop is powered on again, even Magic Sysrq shortcuts doesn't work.
USB Mouse / Keyboards work, so the only thing that can be done to bring back touchpad and keyboard is to reboot the laptop.

I was able to solve the touchpad issue by adding this kernel option in grub:

RUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=1"

But the keyboard issue still remains and I can't figure out what is going wrong here.

Any hint? Thx in advance.

Comment: A common issue that I've seen with some Acer models is that some of the USB busses are not properly re-initialised after suspend. As a result, they remain powered down when the rest of the machine powers up. You can sometimes find evidence for this in `/var/log/syslog`. If this is the issue, then you'll need to add a script that runs post-resume to cycle all of the USB busses. This will create an annoying situation where anything connected to USB is disconnected then reconnected after waking up, which can cause issues with external storage, but you'll have a keyboard (and touchpad) ...

Comment: Thx for the reply... what exactly had this script to do to recycle USB busses?
But when I look at the output of "dmesg" for me it looks like as if the keyboard is not connected to any USB bus, isn't it?

[    0.414413] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4

Comment: And in "lsusb" this isn't seen either:

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2c55 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. HD WebCam
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0489:e04e Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub